# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to update a firebase node but I always get

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument

I think the problem might be that currCount outputs as undefined which is strange because I'm using the same function in other part of the app and works fine.

this is my code:

```js
  
//With this I'm trying to update a node adding +1  
  async addCountRegs(company: string): firebase.Promise<any>{
    var currCount;

    await this.authData.getCountRegs(company)
    .then((countregs:any) => {  
        currCount = countregs.value;
    });   

    console.log('currCount = ' + currCount);

    var regsData = {
      countregs: currCount + 1
    };

    var updates = {};
    updates['/companies/' + company] = regsData;  

    return this.afDB.database.ref().update(updates);

  }
  
//This is the function that should return the current value
async getCountRegs(company: string){
      let firstRef = this.db.object(`companies/${company}`, {preserveSnapshot:true});
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          firstRef.subscribe(snapshot => {
                let a = snapshot.exists();
                if(a) {
                    resolve(snapshot.child("countregs").val());
                }
                });
      
            });
            return promise;
}


//And this is the function which works so I'm not having any issue with this one but you might want to check it out
async maxRegsReached(company: string): Promise<any> {
  var count;
  var max;

  await this.getCountRegs(company)
      .then((usersRef:any) => {  
          count = usersRef;
  });          

  await this.getMaxRegs(company)
      .then((usersRef:any) => {  
          max = usersRef;
  });  

  console.log('count = ' + count);
  console.log('max = ' + max);

  if (count >= max){
    console.log('true');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure! console.log: [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```js
  async addCountRegs(company: string){
    var currCount;

    await this.authData.getCountRegs(company)
    .then((countregs:any) => {  
        currCount = countregs;
    });   

    console.log('currCount = ' + currCount);
 
    let endpoint = this.afDB.object(`/companies/${company}/countregs`); 

    endpoint.set(currCount + 1);

  }
```